# How to get string dump of lxml Element

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have an lxml `Element` object:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> xml_str = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<state type=\"before_battle\">\n</state>"
>>> etree.fromstring(xml_str.encode('utf-8'))
<Element state at 0x7fd04b957e48>
```

How to get the string dump of `Element`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

first store the element object in a variable

```
>>> d = etree.fromstring(xml_str.encode('utf-8'))
```

Then use the `tostring` function from the `lxml.etree` module:

```
>>> etree.tostring(d)
'<state type="before_battle">\n</state>'
```

For additional use cases, you can check out the [`lxml.etree` Tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html).